# OSX Terminal animation

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

In iTerm for OSX I can see all these animated progress bars, while query is in process, for example https://yadi.sk/d/QfHcyNhN3MRqNQ
Is it possible to configure default OSX Terminal to behave like this?

Comment: That's an application running in OSX Terminal.  There are many similar applications which can display progress-bars, and it is not much related to configuring the terminal.

Comment: Yes, I understand that this is application, but situation is different in iTerm and default Terminal, in first case I can see animations, in second picture is static. Here is comparison https://yadi.sk/d/-VXBs4wT3MiQtX

Comment: If I were investigating the difference, I'd capture the output from each program using `script` and compare the escape sequences used.  Being a *programming* group, the way to improve the question would be to point out how to reproduce the example as a script against particular programs.